# Syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: ruby

I have the following as part of a class

```
def to_s
   i = 0
   first_line? = true
   output = ''
   @selections.each do | selection |
      i += 1
      if first_line?
         output << selection.to_s(first_line?)
         first_line? = false
      else
         output << selection.to_s
      end
      if i >= 5
         output << "\r"
         i = 0
      else (output << " $ ")
      end
   end
   return output
end
```

And i am getting the following syntax errors

```
SyntaxError: list2sel.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected '='
    first_line? = true
                 ^
list2sel.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
    @selections.each do | selection |
                       ^
list2sel.rb:51: syntax error, unexpected '='
        first_line? = false
                     ^
```

What give, also thanks in advance, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Variable name contains "?", it should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names (with a few exceptions noted below) can only contain letters, numbers and the underscore. (Also, they must begin with a letter or the underscore; they can't begin with a number.) You can't use `?` or `!` in a variable name.

Beyond that rule, there is a *strong* convention in Ruby that a question mark at the end of something indicates a method that returns a boolean value:

```
4.nil? # => returns false....
```

So even if you could use it, a variable like `first_line?` would confuse (and then annoy) the hell out of Rubyists. They would expect it be a method testing whether something was the first line of something (whatever exactly that means in context).

Exceptions about variable names:

- Global variables begin with `$` - e.g., `$stdin` for standard input.
- Instance variables begin with `@` - e.g. `@name` for an object
- Class variables begin with `@@` - e.g. `@@total` for a class

Comment: is there a standard syntactical way of defining voolean variables?

Comment: With non ASCII letters, you can put all kinds of weird stuff into a variable name.

Comment: Let me ask it another way, Do rubyists prefer a specific way of defining variables that will be boolian such that the reader is clued into the fact that they are boolian. For example, in Objective-C you see isFoo in alot of places.

Comment: @Andrew I wasn't aware of that. It doesn't sound like a good idea, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Ben I don't know of a convention about variables storing booleans in Ruby. There may be one, but it doesn't leap to mind.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose, you can't name variables with '?' at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a more concise way of doing the above (untested):

```
def to_s 
  output = ""
  @selections.each_with_index do | selection,line |  
    output << line==0 ? selection.to_s(true) and next : selection.to_s
    output << line % 5 ? " $ " : "\r"
  end 
  return output 
end
```

If you are not a fan of the ternary operator (x ? y : z) then you can make them ifs:

```
def to_s 
  output = ""
  @selections.each_with_index do | selection,line |  
    if line==0
      output << selection.to_s(true)
    else
      output << selection.to_s
      if line % 5
        output << " $ "
      else
        output << "\r"
      end
    end
  end
  return output 
end
```

Comment: I like this, but there needs to add parentheses ie ( index == 0 ? selection.to_s(true) : selection.to_s ) and ( index % 5 ? " $ " : "\r" )

Answer (score 0):

Variable names allow non-ASCII letters, and there are [non-ASCII versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark#Fullwidth_question_mark) of the question mark, so you can put question marks (and also some forms of space characters) into variable names.

Comment: Again, the clarification is helpful, but I would argue that there's a huge difference (in this case) between what you *can* do and what you *should* do.